# How can I get ICP covariances using laser_scan_matcher?

Tags: ros, icp, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In scan_tools laser_scan_matcher there's a parameter called **do_covariance_computation** which makes laser_scan_matcher calculate covariances but not publish them.

I would like to get the covariances of the ICP, since there's no topic published for this I am trying to get them adding some code to the laser_scan_matcher. At the moment I am adding this

```
std::cout << "cov_x_m: " << output_.cov_x_m->size1 << " " << output_.cov_x_m->size2 << std::endl
```

Doing so I get the following:

```
...
cov_x_m: 3 3 
cov_x_m: 3284753240 3220715007 
cov_x_m: 3 3 
cov_x_m: 3284753240 3220715007 
...
```

If I print the data when size is 3x3 I get something like:

```
...
cov_x_m: 3 3 COV: -0 0.00218628 0.00205292 0.000400059 0.000501095 -0.000222392 -0.00112383 0.000397344 -0.000885956 
cov_x_m: 3 3 COV: 0.000150193 0.00153727 0.00446424 -0.0020142 0.000833389 0.000602156 -0.00217345 0.00121861 -0.00240148 
...
```

My questions are:

- Is this the right way to get this information?
- Why the covariance sizes are not always 3x3?
- Is normal that these covariances are so similar to 0?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12047/how-can-i-get-icp-covariances-using-laser_scan_matcher?/) by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 843 on 2011-11-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anas](https://answers.ros.org/users/736/anas/) on 2011-11-24**:
Same questions here ! can someone give more details in how obtaining the covariances ? Please

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-03-12**:
did you find answer for your problem ?

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2014-03-13**:
This is quite old but I suppose so, at the end I used the code: covariance[0]  = gsl_matrix_get(output_.cov_x_m, 0, 0); to get an element of the 3x3 matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(this is not a complete answer)

Hi,

I am trying to get the covariances of the ICP, I changed the code of laser_scan_matcher.cpp to this

```
geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovariance pose_msg;
  pose_msg.pose.position.x = w2b_.getOrigin().getX();
  pose_msg.pose.position.y = w2b_.getOrigin().getY();
  pose_msg.pose.orientation.z = sin(getYawFromQuaternion(w2b_.getRotation())/2);
  pose_msg.pose.orientation.w = cos(getYawFromQuaternion(w2b_.getRotation())/2);
  pose_msg.covariance[0] = output_.cov_x_m->data[0];
  pose_msg.covariance[1] = output_.cov_x_m->data[1];
  pose_msg.covariance[5] = output_.cov_x_m->data[2];
  pose_msg.covariance[6] = output_.cov_x_m->data[3];
  pose_msg.covariance[7] = output_.cov_x_m->data[4];
  pose_msg.covariance[11] = output_.cov_x_m->data[5];
  pose_msg.covariance[30] = output_.cov_x_m->data[6];
  pose_msg.covariance[31] = output_.cov_x_m->data[7];
  pose_msg.covariance[35] = output_.cov_x_m->data[8];
pose_publisher_.publish(pose_msg);
```

But I am not sure about what I have done (mainly the indexes), can I have a confirmation ?
I also have small values. is the covariance between 0 and 1 ?

Thank you.

---

Originally posted by [Anas](https://answers.ros.org/users/736/anas/) with karma: 126 on 2011-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0